# What is wrong with my code? Did you forget '()'?

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, rf, compilation-errors

```
#include <SimbleeBLE.h>


// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:

const int ButtonPlayPause = 15;
const int ButtonNext = 12;  
const int ButtonPrevious = 11;
const int OBled = 29;   
       int Playp = 1;


// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() 
{

  pinMode(ButtonPlayPause, INPUT);
  pinMode(ButtonNext, INPUT);
  pinMode(ButtonPrevious, INPUT);

  pinMode(OBled, INPUT);

  SimbleeBLE.deviceName = "GBAND";

  Serial.begin(115200);  

  SimbleeBLE.begin();

  SimbleeBLE.txPowerLevel = +4;
}

void loop() 
{ 
  buttonState = digitalRead(ButtonPlayPause);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) 
  {       
    SimbleeBLE.begin();
    SimbleeBLE.deviceName = "GBAND";
    //More code here to establish connection with android
     SimbleeBLE.sendInt = (Playp);
    digitalWrite(OBled, HIGH);
    SimbleeBLE.end();
    digitalWrite(OBled, LOW);
  } else  {  
            buttonState = digitalRead(ButtonNext);
            if (buttonState == HIGH) 
            {
              SimbleeBLE.begin();

              //More code here to establish connection with android

              digitalWrite(OBled, HIGH);
              SimbleeBLE.end();
              digitalWrite(OBled, LOW);
            } else  {  
                      buttonState = digitalRead(ButtonPrevious);
                      if (buttonState == HIGH) 
                      {
                        SimbleeBLE.begin();
                        //More code here to establish connection with android

                        digitalWrite(OBled, HIGH);
                        SimbleeBLE.end();
                        digitalWrite(OBled, LOW);
                      }
                    }
          }
    }
```

---

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows Store 1.8.10.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Simblee"

C:\Users\Lestat\Desktop\SD PROJECR PAPERWORK\Sketch programs\sketch_mar20a\sketch_mar20a.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_mar20a:42: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

     SimbleeBLE.sendInt = (Playp);
                        ^
exit status 1
invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Tagging a question [tag:compilation-errors] and then **not posting them** is the fast track to getting ignored.

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=536567 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a value to a function. That is almost certainly wrong.

```
SimbleeBLE.sendInt(Playp);
```